# angular 2 app works perfect local, but routes doesn't work on server side

Tags: angular, server, routes

like in title, i've got problem with routes on server side, everything works great on local. Every time I try to go into other route than home on server it gives me error in console: GET http://172.17.0.2:3000/student 404 (Not Found) 
its my StudentrouterModule:

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StudentApplicationsComponent } from "./student-applications/student-applications-component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: 'student', component: StudentApplicationsComponent
            }
        ])
        ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StudentRoutingModule {  }
export const routingComponents = [StudentApplicationsComponent] ;
```

there is studentappmodule without imports

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        StudentRoutingModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        StudentApplicationsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ]
})

export class StudentModule{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me. After giving it again run ng build command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hash strategy as it was being used in angular 1

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
 {
   path: 'student', component: StudentApplicationsComponent
 }
 ],{useHash: true});
```

Also check if you have set your base path in index.html file

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: The problem was in the server side.